# Is there a Recipe book?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Is there an in-game recipe book of all the recipes I have learned/discovered? Or do I need to write them all down?

I understand that there is no real structure to creating recipes (the only difference is status effects; or creating elixirs) but I was just wondering if there was any record that I can refer to in-game, because I would prefer it to just random concoctions each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, there's no in-game recipe book that lists all of the recipes you have learned.**

If you keep a single copy of everything you've ever cooked in your inventory, you can fake it. By selecting an item you cooked in your inventory, you can see the ingredients you used to cook it:

[image]

(Image from [Gamespot](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-cooking-tips-and-tricks/1100-6448564/))

Comment: i don't think there's enough inventory space to keep a single copy of every recipe.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an in-game recipe book of all the recipes I have learned/discovered?

No, there is no in-game recipe book (except the workaround Shaun mentioned)

> I was just wondering if there was any record that I can refer to in-game, because I would prefer it to just random concoctions each time.

There is no such system, however, the cooking mechanics are simple enough that you should be able to remember easily enough the short list of things you need to cover each important effect.  Just limit the ingredients you collect in the first place to the ones you want to use, so you don't have other "random stuff" cluttering up your inventory in the first place.

If you're running low on a particular ingredient, the sheika slate's tracking feature can help you find more of that thing as you travel.

For my part, I basically stopped collecting cooking ingredients other than mushrooms and occasionally fish, as they seemed to be the most plentiful, and just cooked with those.  Any other ingredients that ended up in my inventory were sold off for cash.  (I didn't use elixirs very much at all, and subsisted on buying them when I did need them - rupees are not hard to come by in the late game.)